# Pdf viewer in eclipse widget

Tags: java, pdf, widget

I need to embed in an eclipse widget a simple pdf viewer,nothing fancy, just to see the content of the pdf.
Where do i start ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at http://www.jpedal.org/support_siEclipse.php ?

Comment: yes, i have two problems with it : first it is more complex than i need, so i will have to take out some functionality and second, the source code has 2 or 3 errors ..well, if i do not find something better, i will use it ..thanks for the reply

Comment: the source code should have included a  Jpedal_gpl jar file , but it did not ... i found a version and used it

Comment: in the class PDFEditor there is a error at this line  pdfDecoder.getIO().readArray(false, 0, raw.length, PdfDictionary.VALUE_IS_MIXED_ARRAY, raw,
        aData.getObjectRefAsString(), aData, PdfDictionary.Dest,
        null, PdfDictionary.Names);

Comment: in the class PDFSearch there is a error at this line float[] co_ords=currentGrouping.findTextInRectangle(i,textToFind,SearchType.DEFAULT);

Comment: There is a slight API change which breaks it with latest. We are fixing and will reupload).

Comment: You should find it is now fixed in latest update at http://www.jpedal.org/support_siEclipse.php